# query with columns like array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

after trying any hours to add fulltext indexes into my table I found that Like %searchword% works too like that. I get from a first query the array `$keywordse` and after that I create with `$keywordsonetoeight = implode(', ', $keywordse[0]);` a comma seperated list with this output: `string(25) "firstword, secondword, , , , , ,"`. I use mysql and the table runs with MyIsam.

`$keywordse` looks like this:

```
    array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["keyword1"]=> string(0) "" ["keyword2"]=> 
string(5) "ballo" ["keyword3"]=> string(5) "ballo" ["keyword4"]=> 
string(0) "" ["keyword5"]=> string(0) "" ["keyword6"]=> 
string(0) "" ["keyword7"]=> string(0) "" ["keyword8"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

**my query:**

```
"SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE title, text, area, contact LIKE %'$keywordsonetoeight'% AND (autorid != $userid)
ORDER BY id DESC";
```

The output is `NULL`

This works:

```
 "SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE title LIKE '%firstword%' AND (autorid != $userid)
ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `implode()` function directly on your array because several empty elements do exist in the array. First unset the empty array elements from your `$keywordse[0]` array, and then use `REGEXP` for your search.

Your code should be like this:

```
foreach($keywordse[0] as $key => $value){
    if(empty(trim($value))){
        unset($keywordse[0][$key]);
    }
}

$conditions = implode("|", $keywordse[0]);

$query = "SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE (title REGEXP '{$conditions}' 
OR text REGEXP '{$conditions}' 
OR contact REGEXP '{$conditions}') 
AND autorid <> {$userid} 
ORDER BY id DESC";

// Now execute this $query
```

Here's the reference:

- [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Here I get ´array(0) { }´ too. But Ive checked that the array values are the same how in an column

Comment: @Bodoppels Are you still getting `NULL`? If yes then please update your question with the contents of `$keywordse` array.

Comment: No I get `array(0) { }`. If I echo `$conditions` I get `string(17) "|ballo|ballo|||||"`. The columns have an index and are fulltext is there a problem maybe?

Comment: @Bodoppels Oh, my mistake. `unset($key)` should be `unset($keywordse[0][$key])`, I've updated the `foreach` loop, now it should work fine. Please test your application with the updated code.

Comment: if I echo now `$conditions` I get `string(5) "Array"` should this be so?

Comment: @Bodoppels No, it should echo `ballo|ballo`.

Comment: Ok I thought too. Does that happens from the loop? Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @Bodoppels The `foreach` removes all the empty values from the array. What exactly do you have in `$keywordse[0]` array? Please update your question with the same.

Comment: @Bodoppels Found the bug. `$conditions = implode("|", $keywordse);` should be `$conditions = implode("|", $keywordse[0]);`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Bodoppels Glad I could help. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want compare all values in your array you can user REGEXP:

```
"SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE title REGEXP '$first_word|$second_word|$third_word' 
OR text REGEXP '$first_word|$second_word|$third_word' )  AND (autorid != $userid)
ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: That doesnt change something, I get ´NULL´.

Comment: Thank you, I need the second query but I get NULL, if I change one ´'%$keywordsonetoeight%'´ with a word that in an column in posts exists it works otherwise with your code dont. Anything must be wrong with the syntax in the query at the array

Comment: try the query after updating